# Can I get fruit from an olive tree in the UK?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, olive

Our local garden centre has some mature olive trees reduced substantially, but still by no means cheap.

We're in a secluded spot in North East England; is getting fruit from an olive tree this far north fragile or are such trees purely ornamental for us?

Comment: What will be the use? Oil? You need many many olives. Olives to eat? You need a large jar, or it will be costly the process to transform tree olives into edible olives.

Comment: The only time i managed to get fruit on a potted olive tree here in Texas, was when I left it out for winter to get frosted. They don't like too much frost, but we had it in a sheltered spot (a small courtyard next to the kitchen window). (alas it later died after too many temporary house moves meant it died of drought)

Comment: Maybe in a glass house?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is very unlikely you will get fruit from your olive tree. Sometimes in the south east of the UK in a hot summer, some fruit might be set, but rarely - where you are, it's even less likely, These trees are listed as 'frost hardy' by the RHS, so protection from the elements during winter may be necessary  https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=138